# Can I visualize binary trees in d3 with this data

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, dataframe, d3.js

So I have this index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="treeDiv"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([400, 400]);

    var data = {{ data.chart_data | safe }}    

    console.log(data);

    </script>
</body>
</html
```

and in console it prints this:

[image: console output]

I wanted to use [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/ceb8d9e5ded610a9df1e0adb98efd748) code or [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8326869) code, to visualize the trees. 
But I cant bring the data in that format. So is there a way to visualize trees from the format I have now? 
The first tree should look like this:
[image: how the tree should look like]

If you want to see how I pass the data in python:

```
tree_definitions = robjects.globalenv['treedefinitions']

df2 = tree_definitions.drop(['nodes', 'classes'], axis=1)

tree_data = df2.to_dict(orient='records')
tree_data = json.dumps(tree_data, indent=2)
data = {'chart_data': tree_data}
# return data
return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your tree structure is just an array. There is no indication of which 2 nodes are connected.

You will at least need to store the parent/children for each node in the tree otherwise it is impossible to build a tree from just an array.

Comment: right, and in the array there are 8 different tree structures. So what is your suggestion how can I achieve this that you're saying?

Comment: @poweredbygt You will have to store the parent/child relation for each node. Use the example you posted.